# Why does coveralls show 0% coverage when every source file is 100% covered?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, coveralls

I made a simple C++ project which I hooked up to travis and coveralls. As far as I know, I'm uploading the reports correctly as my source files are shown in coveralls and are 100% covered.

However, the project coverage shows 0%. Why, and how to fix?

[image]

Comment: The latest run was _a day ago_, so try to rerun it and see what happens. Also, try clearing your browser's cache.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to mismatched gcov and g++ versions.

The build logs give the following messages

> adder.cpp.gcno:version '408*', prefer '406*'

This is why the columns all register `0` in the above screenshot. When the gcov and g++ versions match, the output looks like the following

[image]

Coveralls just makes this error a little tricky to uncover because each file is flagged as 100% covered if there are no relevant lines, but the summary shows 0% for this state